# Linear increase of collector current in CE mode of a BJT

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, diodes, bjt, biasing

Why is there first, a linear increase in the collector current in the output characteristics of an NPN BJT in CE configuration if we increase the Vce(collector-emitter) and then the current remains almost constant.?Is there an easy explaination? My book just has the graph but doesn't provide an explanation.[image]

Comment: Be more concrete. Draw schematic.

Comment: Try to see the bjt as a reverse biased diode whose inverse saturation current can be changed by injecting carriers at the emitter. Then each of those curves becomes the diode vi characteristic for progressively more reverse biasing voltages. So what you think is linear is in reality a part of an exponential curve.

Comment: Is it like the reverse bias i-v curve of a diode? But the graph has certainly more slope than the reverse bias curve of a diode which rises very slowly? What's the reason?

Answer (score -1):

Changing Vce barely changes the collector current because the collector of a common-emitter transistor is a current source so the voltage barely changes its current. The very small change is the Early effect.